# Python: Integrate product of exponential and gaussian function

Tags: python, sympy, exponential, integral

I have a function y which is a product of y1 = exp(-x) and exp(-x^2):

> y1 = exp(-x)
>
> y2 = exp(-x**2)
>
> y = y1*y2 = exp(-x)*exp(-x**2) = exp(-x **2-x)

Integrating the functions y1 or y2 works fine using sympy:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = sy.Symbol('x')
>>> y1 = sy.exp(-x)
>>> sy.integrate(y1, (x, 0, np.inf))
1
```

and

```
>>> y2 = sy.exp(-x**2)
>>> sy.integrate(y2, (x, 0, np.inf))
0.5*sqrt(pi)
```

However, whenever I'm trying to integrate the product y1*y2 = y, the integral is not accepted:

```
>>> y = y1*y2
>>> sy.integrate(y, (x, 0, np.inf))
Integral(exp(-x)*exp(-x**2), (x, 0, np.inf))
```

Perhaps I'm blind and missing something obvious.

Comment: It's not raising any error? `Integral(exp(-x)*exp(-x**2), (x, 0, np.inf))` is the entire return output?

Comment: @jphollowed not giving me any errors, just this very output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sympy cannot evaluate it symbolically, then it just returns an Integral object.  You need to either use a more powerful symbolic calculator like [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) or [Wolfram|Alpha (link to solution)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(exp(-x)*exp(-x**2),%20x,%200,%20inf))), or else resort to numerical integration.  Here are a few options for numerically integrating it:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate

x = sy.Symbol('x')
y1 = sy.exp(-x)
y2 = sy.exp(-x**2)
y = y1*y2

# Pure scipy without sympy
print(sp.integrate.quad(lambda x: np.exp(-x) * np.exp(-(x**2)), 0, np.inf))

# Mix of scipy and sympy
print(sp.integrate.quad(lambda x_arg: y.subs(x, x_arg).evalf(), 0, np.inf))

# Without using scipy
print(sy.mpmath.quad(sy.lambdify([x], y), [0, np.inf]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Looks like I'm sticking to numerical integration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Integral *is* being accepted and it is giving you a valid sympy result.  I used [this site](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and it indicates (I am not enough of a mathematician to verify it) the answer has the error function (erf) in it:

[image]

There is no exact analytical answer, so it is giving you it's internal representation.  I used Mathematica years ago and it would do something similar, but it provided a polynomial approximation to the solution.  BTW, the answer is approximately 0.5456413607650471.

I used http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to generate the equation image.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, integrating this type of function tends to produce an error function erf(x), like the one you mentioned.